# Bad behavior while checking if domain exist

Tags: java

I want to check if a domain exist, so here is my code :

```
try {
    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("ouestfrance-ecole.com");
    System.out.println(inetAddress.getHostName());
    System.out.println(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the response is :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: ouestfrance-ecole.com
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:849)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1202)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1153)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1083)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1019)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:969)
at MainApp.main(MainApp.java:18)
```

But If I put ouestfrance-ecole.com in my browser or execute `host ouestfrance-ecole.com` I have a response cause the domain really exist and host a website.

What are the reasons ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InetAddress.getByName("www.ouestfrance-ecole.com")
```

works fine (notice the `www` subdomain). It's the `ouestfrance-ecole.com` that doesn't work (also in my browser).